# Kafka Integration Test, unable to set SASL enabled mechanism

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, testcontainers

I'm doing integration testing with `TestContainers` and trying to enable SASL so I can keep the same configuration file and not duplicate code.

```java
  public static KafkaContainer kafka =
      new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse(KAFKA_TEST_IMAGE))
              .withNetwork(Network.newNetwork())
              .withEnv("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "false")
              .withEnv("KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND", "true")
              .withEnv("KAFKA_SUPER_USERS", "User:OnlySuperUser")
//              .withEnv("KAFKA_CFG_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS", "PLAIN")
//              .withEnv("KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
              .withEnv("KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS", "PLAIN,SASL_PLAINTEXT")
              .withEnv("KAFKA_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG", JAAS_CONFIG);
```

Here is what I'm playing with, but I get the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.IllegalSaslStateException: Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are []
```

It seems like the enabled mechanism (PLAIN) is being completely ignored. Why is this? I checked the documentation and don't see how else I could configure this within the container.

Comment: What image are you using?

Comment: I'm using latest currently. I'ved tried on v5.x and v6.x

Comment: I've spent several hours trying to get the enabled mechanism to change to something other than empty list and couldn't find anything to get it populated.